# Split string in java using regex

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I'd like to split text at the begining and the end some tags (div and p) not all of them.

```
Input:
String html = "text<div>some text</div><tag>text</tag><span>asd</span><p>text</p>text";

Output:
text
<div>some text</div>
<tag>text</tag><span>asd</span>
<p>text</p>
text
```

What regex should i use?

Comment: A regex called HTML parser.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Try using an HTML parse like JSoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could **split** it with this regex

```
(?<=</(div|p)>)|(?=<(div|p)>)
```

But as others recommended use an html parser..

---

But why use parser..

Consider above regex. It won't work

- if you have nested tags..(NO **REGEX** could solve this problem..It's **next** to impossible)
- if the tags have attributes
- if you have arbitrary number of space within tag

---

Though,its unclear why you want to do this split